# Reverting a CoreStorage Volume

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, core-storage

I broke an installation of Deep Freeze on a Macbook by upgrading it to El Capitan. I'd like to get Deep Freeze to work again, but "This version of Deep Freeze cannot be installed on a Mac that has CoreStorage volume". There are many guides to reverting a CoreStorage volume on the internet, but the steps aren't working for me.

I open terminal and type "diskutil cs list" and get the list of volumes on the Macbook, the revertible area tells me "Yes (no decryption required)". When I type "diskutil cs revert [logical volume UUID]" I get the error "The given UUID is not a valid CoreStorage Logical Volume UUID. I erased the hard drive and installed El Capitan fresh making sure to uncheck FileVault when I was setting it up, but I'm still getting the same error. Is there another method for disabling CoreStorage on Macbooks that I'm not aware of? Appreciate any help regarding this.

Comment: Your case is  strange since it should be possible to install El Capitan without using Core Storage, _if you do not have a Fusion drive_. You could try creating a USB bootable installer, then after booting from the installer, create a regular HFS+ partition to install El Capitan on to. I know it is possible to install El Captan without using Core Storage since all three of my Macs are setup this way.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up stumbling across the answer to my own questions (although David is right, I could have avoided it by following his steps). The guides I found all pointed to the first UUID, but it's actually the 4th one after running the disktutil cs list command. Simple, but took me forever to find. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to erase the disk again:

```
diskutil cs delete <UUID of Logical Volume Group>
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the command you posted will fix the OP's problem.  Providing additional info can also help the OP, and others, evaluate your answer themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review -